# IBM Security Access Manager Integration with MobileFirst 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, isam

i am working on a MobileFirst application. It needs to be integrated with IBM security access manager. i have configured the login modules, realms and authentication configurations. On the code side, what should be done?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the help for this product: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034222

> The integration package includes sample applications and adapter to
>   validate successful HTTP header or LTPA token integration, single
>   sign-on to backend data sources using Worklight Adapters, OAuth
>   authentication, context/risk-based access, Device Single Sign-On and
>   MobileFirst Platform Foundation generated Certificate Authentication. 
>   The sample applications and challenge handlers are intended to be used
>   as references for developing your own IBM MobileFirst Platform
>   Foundation mobile application integration with IBM Security Access
>   Manager.